# Selecting the user which isn't me

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables, Users and Games.

Users

```
users_id, profile_pic, username
1, rita.jpg, Rita
2, sue.jpg, Sue
```

Games

```
games_id, player_1_users_id, player_2_users_id, status
1, 1, 2, 3
```

I'm trying to make a join to return the user profile pic of the user which doesn't have my users_id

So, if I'm users_id 2, I want the SQL to return the profile_pic for player_1, and visa versa.

I have this so far, but I'm a little way off at the moment, as this obviously just returns my profile_pic, not the other users:

```
SELECT  u.profile_pic
              FROM games g 
              JOIN users u ON (u.users_id = g.player_1_users_id OR u.users_id = g.player_2_users_id)
              WHERE 
              (player_1_users_id = 2 OR player_2_users_id = 2) AND
              g.status = 3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Expected result? [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "So, if I'm users_id 2, I want the SQL to return the profile_pic for player_1, and visa versa." i doubt the users table remains at two user only?

Comment: If I'm users_id 2, I would expect it to return users_id 1 profile_pic, which is rita.jpg

Comment: Correct, there will be hundreds of users.

Comment: Yes.. But what happens when there are more users and games?

Comment: There is only ever two users per game, and I'm returning the games with a status = 3, and that my users_id is either player_1 or player_2.

Comment: Yes.. But a user can exist in more games at the same time? for example you play against Rita and me at the same time?

Comment: Correct. A user can be in lots of status = 3 games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left join the users twice and include the exclusion of ID 2 in the `ON` clause. Get the profile picture, that isn't `NULL` using `coalesce()`.

```
SELECT g.games_id,
       coalesce(u1.profile_pic,
                u2.profile_pic) profile_pic
       FROM games g
            LEFT JOIN users u1
                      ON u1.users_id = g.player_1_users_id
                         AND g.player_1_users_id <> 2
            LEFT JOIN users u2
                      ON u2.users_id = g.player_2_users_id
                         AND g.player_2_users_id <> 2
       WHERE 2 IN (g.player_1_users_id,
                   g.player_2_users_id)
             AND g.status = 3;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=81a3b185707997a4eb8411f8aabbe64a)